# How can I load an FB like button, preferably in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to include http://jonathanscorner.com/like.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fjonathanscorner.com in an iframe, and when I load the URL by itself, it reports errors (the "Like" doesn't stick) and says to lint it, but I can't tell from the linter what would be causing trouble (other than people being unable to give multiline comments).

How can I get this working, and/or is there a way to include it with a document.write()-based JavaScript include, evil as it may be? The URL above is something like a minimal test case that shows some of the same problems as when I was trying to work from document.write(), but without including any dirty programmer's tricks on the page.

Comment: I heard someone comment that he needed to make a phone call to get an ID token of some sort; if I need to follow up by phone or other means to register as a developer, how can I do that?

Comment: you want to include an iframe in an iframe, hopefully it is not working! As I understood you want to put the like button in an external website and when user will like, it will like your page?

Comment: I want something on the same page; the iframe was intended as a way to avoid document.write()s. What should the iframe or other text look like for e.g. inclusion on http://jonathanscorner.com/ or http://jonathanscorner.com/library/ ?

Comment: If you want somthing on the same page, why do you want to use an iframe? just copy paste the code from facebook...

Comment: I don't want to load the full SDK if I can avoid it. There's Crockford among others saying that if you have JavaScript from two or more sources running on the same page, you're automatically unsecure. I was hoping for a light, easy way to allow sharing of my page instead of a dive into the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and type in your url and click get code, then choose the iframe option from the code drop down you'll see:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=153916771364199&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fjonathanscorner.com%2Flike.cgi%3Furl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fjonathanscorner.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Make sure that's your app id in the iframe, and set up OG tags on your page to help the linter pull in the data properly.